# Does Hugin support stitching pictures of the Moon?

Tags: astrophotography, hugin

I'm trying to stitch two incomplete pictures of the Moon together by using Hugin, but it doesn't find even one single control point, so I'll have to combine everything by hand. Here are the two pics I'd like to stitch:

[image: upper part]
[image: lower part]

Both pics have been shot with an EOS 1100D and a 1400 / 100 Maksutov lens.

So, is there a trick or hack to make Hugin perform a stitch of pictures of the Moon?

**UPDATE:** After giving Hugin a second try, I still get only one frame (the upper one) in the fast panorama preview. The lower frame is completely missing! Hugin does find 25 control points, yet I had to switch off geometric optimisation (angle too low) and ideal panorama size (which would have been > 1E+5). My version of Hugin is: 2018.0.0

Answer (score 6):

With the images you supplied, Hugin (version 2020.0) had no problem automatically finding control points. As you can see, the distance was very good (zero is desired outcome) with average control point distance = 1.36, standard deviation = 0.82, and maximum distance = 3.39.

From the Photos tab:
I used Hugin's CPFind to generate control points.
Optimized geometric Positions (incremental, starting from anchor).

Stiched image from the Stitcher tab.

Edit:
Not sure if the images you used are exactly like the ones you posted. As depicted in the Hugin GUI image below, I removed the transparent areas before moving them in to Hugin.

[image: HuginControlPoints]

[image: Stiched image]

Comment: Strange! :/ But as I tried this in 2017 for the last time, maybe my version of Hugin is simply outdated.

Comment: @Neppomuk CPFind was probably the default control point generator in 2017. I think CPFind has been around since 2010, an outcome of a Google Summer of Code project. Hugin had to make their own control point generator since some uni couldn't give them an answer on usage terms to use their CPG that was in use at that point in time. CPFind turned out, at that time, to be a superior CPG.

Comment: OK, I retried everything with Hugin 2018, but no use. It's not the contro points BTW, but Hugin omits the lower frame when stitching.

Comment: @Neppomuk Do your image have blank space as depicted in the images you posted? If so, crop the images as I did in my posted example before importing to Hugin.

Comment: @Neppomuk One other thought came to mind. Hugin is sensitive to alpha channels. Be sure to flatten the images before processing in Hugin. Hugin uses alpha channels to mask and control blending. See [Hugin documentation](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Alpha_channel.html)

Comment: I used the original stacked images in TIFF format without alphas or blanks.